# Duplicate Column next to original Column based on a header name

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched quite a bit for this but keep finding where people want to copy to another sheet and that's not what I want. I want to just duplicate a column labeled "Student ID" since it isn't always in column D and to reference the Active Sheet since the sheet isn't always named Sheet1. The additional code then adds a 0 to the end of the data in the new duplicated column and labels the new column "Patron". I am fairly new to VBA so struggling with this.

```
Range("D:D").Copy
Range("E:E").Insert
Range("E1").Value = "PATRON"

Range("IV1") = 10
Range("IV1").Copy
Range("E1:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply
Range("IV1").Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *"adds a 0 to the end of the data"* adds a new row with value `0` at the end of that column?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use Find to locate header and Concatenate to add the zero.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()

    Const COL_NAME = "Student ID"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, LastRow As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Cells.Find(COL_NAME, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not locate column '" & COL_NAME & "'", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        r = rng.Row
        c = rng.Column
        LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Columns(c + 1).Insert
        ws.Cells(r, c + 1) = "PATRON"
        Set rng = ws.Cells(r + 1, c + 1).Resize(LastRow - r)
        rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-1],0)"
        'rng.Value2 = rng.Value2 'uncomment if you want values not fomulae
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following could work:

```
Option Explicit   

Public Sub Example()
    DuplicateColumn ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet, "Student ID", "PATRON"
End Sub


Public Sub DuplicateColumn(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal HeaderName As String, ByVal NewColumnName As String)
    ' find the header name
    Dim ColumnFound As Range
    Set ColumnFound = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:=HeaderName, _
                                      After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), _
                                      LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                      SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                      MatchCase:=False)
    ' check if it was found
    If ColumnFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Column '" & HeaderName & "' was not found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' copy that column
    With ColumnFound.EntireColumn
        .Copy
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Insert
    End With
    
    ' give the new column a new name
    ColumnFound.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = NewColumnName
    
    ' add 0 at the end of that column
    ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ColumnFound.Column + 1).End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1).Value = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code finds the column labeled "Student ID" and inserts a new column then copies the data to the new column.   Since I'm not sure about what the rest of the code does, I'll leave that to you.  Also, to a a zero at the endd of a cell 's data, just do something like cells(row, Col+1).value = cells(row, Col+1).value & "0"

```
Set sht = ActiveSheet  'set variable to active sheet
' Finds the column NUMBER for Student ID
Col = sht.Rows(1).Find(What:="Student ID", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

Columns(Col + 1).Insert     'insert new column
Columns(Col).Copy Columns(Col + 1)  'copy Student ID column data to new column
Cells(1, Col + 1).Value = "PATRON"   'add header to new column
```

Comment: This looks great - the only thing I cant get to work then is the 0 at the end. ID Numbers are 1234 and I need the Patron Numbers to be 12340. The code you provided keeps erroring on that part.

Comment: See CDP1802's answer for that part.